# Is my Windows 7 primary and secondary DNS setting correct?

Tags: windows, networking, dns, nameservers

I use a Windows 7 desktop PC with a TP Link Wireless N ADSL2 + Modem Router.

My PC is connected to the TP Link via a LAN cable while another 2 PCs of my secretaries are connected via WiFi.

I am not good at networking. I wonder if my primary and secondary settings are correct.

I can see there are 2 places to set the pri and sec DNS:

1) in Windows adapter setting IPv4

2) in TP Link's control panel

- And I don't understand why there are two places to make the settings.

Since I am not sure what to do, I have posted the screenshots of the settings and also the test results of Namebench and DNS Jumper.

Hopefully someone can tell me whether I should use 192.168.1.1 as it seems that it is my local LAN IP address.... or what is the best setting to use?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Off-topic.Try on superuser.com!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was the one who commented your question,but,I am the one who is also leaving the answer here.

Basically, the two around which you are confused are two different things.

Also,firstly,the IP-Address must not be equal to the IP-Address of the router as it will give an error of `IP-Address resolution error!` because IP-Address of your router and IP-Address of your PC are same.

Secondly, you just need to leave the 'DNS Server address` in your PC to

```
Obtain DNS Server Address Automatically.
```

And,in your router configure the exact DNS-Server Address of your Internet Connection.The router settings must be saved and made permanent by finally updating it.Finally,reboot the router(don't reset!!!)---just a power off and on.

This will solve all your query and you'll be done setting up your network. If you have further doubt,please leave a comment below.

Comment: Answering blatantly off-topic questions (which you even pointed out) only encourages more off-topic posting.